# Condition inclusion through has-include-expression and has-attribute-expression behaves differently

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

```cpp
#include <iostream>

#define Abc likely
# if __has_cpp_attribute(Abc)
#define Pn 0
#endif 

#if __has_cpp_attribute(likely)
#ifndef Pn
#define Pn 1
#endif
#endif
int main(){
   std::cout<< Pn;
}
```

For this [example](https://godbolt.org/z/bK8sTejdY), GCC prints `0` while Clang prints `1`. According to [cpp.cond] p5

> Each has-attribute-expression is replaced by a non-zero pp-number matching the form of an integer-literal if the implementation supports an attribute with the name specified by interpreting the pp-tokens, **after macro expansion**, as an attribute-token, and by 0 otherwise. The program is ill-formed if the pp-tokens do not match the form of an attribute-token.

So, the directive `# if __has_cpp_attribute(Abc)` should behave the same as `#if __has_cpp_attribute(likely)`. GCC has the right behavior. Again, consider this example

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#define Head <iostream>
# if __has_include(Head)
#define Pn 0
#endif 

#ifndef Pn
#define Pn 1
#endif
int main(){
   std::cout<< Pn;
}
```

In this [example](https://godbolt.org/z/z3jjTMY7Y), both compilers print `0`. However, according to [cpp.cond] p4

> The header or source file identified by the parenthesized preprocessing token sequence in each contained has-include-expression is searched for as if that preprocessing token sequence were the pp-tokens in a #include directive, **except that no further macro expansion is performed**. If such a directive would not satisfy the syntactic requirements of a #include directive, the program is ill-formed. The has-include-expression evaluates to 1 if the search for the source file succeeds, and to 0 if the search fails.

Note the bold wording, which means `Head` won't be replaced by `<iostream>`, there is no such a source file. Hence, `Pn` should be `1` instead. Could it be considered a bug of GCC and Clang?

Comment: MSVC passes the first example, but fails the second as well (assuming correct interpretations in the question): https://godbolt.org/z/GcT4TKoEr

Comment: @user17732522  MSVC also accepts the [second one](https://godbolt.org/z/MszsGbnEa)

Comment: I was referrring to _fails_ in the sense of _failing the spec according to the interpretation in the question_. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: [\[cpp.cond\]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/cpp.cond#3) says if the tokens in `__has_include(...)` are not a *header-name*, then they are processed "just as in normal text". It doesn't say what "just as in normal text" means, but the same phrase also appears in [\[cpp.include\]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/cpp.include#4.sentence-2), followed by a parenthetical remark that says macro replacement is performed.

Comment: ... so I think printing `0` is correct for your second example.

Comment: @cpplearner I would have assumed that "the preprocessing tokens" would refer to the _h-pp-tokens_ inside `__has_­include(<h-pp-tokens>)` only. That is also the position that [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/include) seems to take. Although that does seem unintended to me.

Comment: @cpplearner The characters in `<...>` and in `"..."` are not replaced by a macro replacement as per [cpp.include]. The only one that can be replaced is it does not conform to either of the above forms, as stated in [cpp.include] p4. Neither of the forms of the two has-include-expression can have the form of that specified in [cpp.include] p4.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure that the answer below is correct. I will leave it up for reference for now.

---

I think the second example does not fit the *has-include-expression* grammar. If you look at [[cpp.cond]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/cpp.cond) there are two forms mentioned, which are further subdivided into multiple cases, referring also to [[lex.header]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/lex.header).

Collecting the possible forms and combining them here for presentation, we get:

```
__has_include(<...>)
__has_include("...")
__has_include(string-literal)
```

with `...` as some placeholder and `string-literal` any string literal. Your form `__has_include(Head)` is none of these, since `Head` neither starts with `"`, nor `<`, nor is it a string literal.

[[cpp.cond]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/cpp.cond#3) does mention that if the first of the two syntax choices for *has-include-expression* does not match, the second is considered and *the preprocessor tokens* are processed like normal text, presumably meaning they are macro-expanded. However it is not clear to me whether this is supposed to reference all preprocessor tokens between `(` and `)` before the above-mentioned grammar rules are applied or just the *h-pp-tokens* in the `__has_include(<h-pp-tokens>)` form. In the former case, the compilers would be correct in returning `0`.

However, the latter case makes more sense to me, especially when comparing e.g. to the grammar rule for `#include`, which uses similar forms, but instead of `#include <h-pp-tokens>` the last form is `#include pp-tokens`. [[cpp.include]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/cpp.include#4)

[[cpp.cond]/7](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/cpp.cond#7) says that the identifier `__has_include` *shall not* appear in any context not mentioned in the subclause. I would think that *shall not* here means *otherwise ill-formed*, in which case the program should not compile without diagnostic. If it means *otherwise undefined behavior*, then all compilers are correct.

---

For the first example, I think you are right. Clang has a recently-fixed bug report regarding the macro expansion [here](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/47806) and if you choose Clang trunk on compiler explorer, the result will coincide with GCC already now.

Comment: Your interpretation seems right on the second example. The program should be ill-formed, hence it is still a bug. That being said, I have to say the meaning of `__has_include(Head)` is a bit obscure.

Comment: I would say the macro-expanded cannot be performed for a string-literal even if there is any identifier-like subsequence in its sequence. See [cpp.replace#footnote-137]: Since, by macro-replacement time, all character-literals and string-literals are preprocessing tokens, not sequences possibly containing identifier-like subsequences (see [lex.phases], translation phases), they are never scanned for macro names or parameters.  `__has_include(string-literal)` is this case, let alone `Head` is neither a string-literal, `"..."`  or `<...>` head name.